# How to detect click with native html/css for slider

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

I am trying to create slider only with html/css. I'm using inputs and labels.

This is my css code. I'm moving my div to left when element is checked.

`.firstCat:checked ~ .carousel-wrapper div { left: 360px; transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out; }`

Is it the only way to create sider? Maybe you more elegant solution.

Comment: "Elegance" is an opinion, which is explicitly [off-topic](/help/dont-ask) here. There are many, many ways of creating "sliders"; searching this site will find a large number of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider">
```

You can use input type "range".